# NavigationManager.NavigateTo() does not work after running a method

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-7.0

looking desperately for some help...

I have a .Net7 server-side Blazor app that is working as expected (sort of). I have added a login page where the user puts in their Username and Password into the screen and hits submit. What should happen then is

- Check there is data in the Username and Password, displaying an alert if not
- Run a method that triggers a Stored Procedure on the database (I use ADO and not EF)
- Count the number of items in the `List<Family>` (this is created in the above method)
- Navigate to a new page where the count is greater than 0 or display an alert if not

OK. The problem lies in the method somehow. When I run the code, the `List<Family>` is populated from the database. I can do the check in the razor component and I can see I have more than 1 item in the list or not. When the check is done, I can then either trigger the navigate method or the alert methods and it runs through those in debug. The issue is that in the UI the screen does not change to the new page or when an alert is expected does not display.

No error messages are displayed just the originating screen.

Ah, you may think, this is a problem with the Navigate or Alert methods!!! Well, if I place the navigate and/or the alert methods **before** the `GetFamilies()` method (which populates the `list<Family>` the navigation and/or the alert works fine.

What I don't understand is why :( I have removed all the async methods so it should run synchronously. I have re-coded this loads of times and ways including using a cache, using async, using `Task.WaitAll()`. It seems where the app needs to contact the database something happens that means although the code is run it doesn't update the UI. I have even checked the Threads and going into the `GetFamilies()` is the same coming out and during the method.

Note that the `ReturnData.GetFamilies()` method works fine and does not use anything async and is a different method to `GetFamilies()` in this razor page.

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Form in the Blazor component

```
<form>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="userName" class="form-label">Username</label>
        <input @bind="LocalLogin.UserName" type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" aria-describedby="userNameHelp" placeholder="User Name">
        <div id="userNameHelp" class="form-text">Please use the username and password provided with your invite.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="userPassword" class="form-label">Password</label>
        <input @bind="LocalLogin.Password" type="password" class="form-control" id="userPassword" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => Authenticate()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Authenticate Method

```
    private void Authenticate()
    {
        if (!ValidLoginDetails())
        {
            return;
        }
        GetFamilies();
        if(Families.Count > 0)
        {
            Navigate();
        }
        else
        {
            Alert("Your credentials have not been recognised");
        }
    }
```

Get Families method

```
    private void GetFamilies()
    {
        string localConnectionString = config.GetConnectionString("SQLServerConnection");
        Families = ReturnData.GetFamilies(localConnectionString, LocalLogin);
    }
```

Navigate and Alert Methods

```
    private void Navigate()
    {
        navManager.NavigateTo("/ufr", true, true);
    }

    private void Alert(string argMessage)
    {
        js.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", argMessage);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
<button type="submit" ...>Submit</button>
```

with

```
<button type="button" ...>Submit</button>
```

You have a `<form>` with an actual submit button. That will do an actual POST to your server and that won't be handled.

Even better would be using an `<EditForm>` but that's a matter of choice.